# Counting data-containing lines from a file in C

Tags: c, file

I'm a college student currently learning C and I need to create a function that opens a file and counts the number of data-containing lines then returns the value. I am having trouble trying to read from more than one line from the file.

This is what I have as of now.

Note:  These are defined in another file

```
#define FNAME "sample_data.txt"
#define NAMELEN 30
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "utility.h"

int get_datafile_size(char file_name) 
{
    FILE* fp = fopen(FNAME, "r");
    int datalines = 0;

    while (!feof(fp))
    {
        char temp_str[NAMELEN];

        fgets(temp_str, NAMELEN - 1, fp);
        
        if (temp_str[0] != "#" && temp_str[0] != " ")
        {
            datalines++;
        }
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    printf("<%d>", datalines);
    return datalines;
}
```

Currently the function only outputs the number of characters in the first line.

For reference here is the file in question:

```
# These records are in the form EMPLOYEE_NAME:EMPLOYEE_ID:EMPLOYEE_SALARY
# The following are administrators::
Eric Braun:174328:240378.94
Sunil Ahuja:285832:190415.87

# The following are staff members:
Joe Smith:132754:25018.14
Sally Jones:158113:32019.55
Janice P Oliver:185639:11458.32
Robert North:317543:85321.11
Janice J Oliver:298734:47166.76

# The following are student workers:
Davy Crockett:345216:5372.18
Billy Bones:239954:1141.66
Amanda Nice:398751:514.32
Tiny T Tim:301865:1093.54
```

And the function outputs:

```
<27>
```

Comment: [Why is “while( !feof(file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong)

Comment: A newline (`\n') character indicates a line. Your code is not handling that.

Comment: *I am having trouble trying to read from more than one line from the file.* How do you know how many lines are read from the file? *I am having trouble trying to read from more than one line from the file.* If is rather unlikely that this function does that. Please show the input file and the output the function produces.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `char file_name` parameter?

Comment: Look at the first line in the data file. Look at the size of the buffer (`30`)... `fgets()` will load `30-1`-1 characters (the extra -1 so there's room to fulfill the guarantee of a NUL terminated string). Result? The first line will be processed in several segments, throwing off the count wildly...

Comment: Crashzen, as the file may have more than `INT_MAX` lines, consider `int datalines = 0;` --> `long long datalines = 0;`.  True that a file _could_ have more than `LLONG_MAX` lines, but that case if far less likely.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `INT_MAX`... More than 2 billion entries in a flat file... What is this? Facebook??? `:-)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many issues in the code!

`int get_datafile_size(char file_name)`

- Inappropriate function name

- `char` is not `char *` indicating a C string file name

`FILE* fp = fopen(FNAME, "r");`

- What is `FNAME`?

`while (!feof(fp))`

- Don't use `feof()`... Just don't!

`char temp_str[NAMELEN];` // NAMELEN = 30

- Good to use token instead of *magic number*. Bad to limit buffer size.

`fgets(temp_str, NAMELEN - 1, fp);`

- Presuming `-1` is thoughtfully accounting for `'\0'`. Don't worry. `fgets()` takes that into account and guarantees a NUL terminated string will be returned. `fgets()` will not overrun the buffer as long as the correct buffer size is provided to it.

- The buffer and the token may be changed separately. Better to use `sizeof temp_str` allowing compiler to use the up-to-date size of the buffer.

`if (temp_str[0] != "#" && temp_str[0] != " ")`

- Mixing up single character with strings containing one character AND a terminating NUL character. Use *apostrophes*, not *double quotes*.

`printf("<%d>", datalines);`

- Assuming this to be a "print debugging statement. Without `'\n'`, this output may not be pushed through the buffer when expected.

Better to use: `fprintf( stderr, "datalines<%d>\n", datalines );`

---

Better if the function has no expectations about the length of any line in the file. This can be handled by processing individual characters (from the stream's buffered input, so speed is not severely reduced.)

```
int cnt_datalines( char *file_name ) {
    FILE *fp = fopen( file_name, "r" );
    if( fp == NULL )
        return -1; // let caller handle the error

    int datalines = 0;
    int ch;
    for( int bgn = 1; ( ch = fgetc( fp ) ) != EOF; bgn = ch == '\n' )
        // Add 1 only when 1st char after newline is not hash, SP or newline
        datalines += ( bgn && ch != '\n' && ch != '#' && ch != ' ' );

    fclose(fp);

    fprintf( stderr, "datalines <%d>\n", datalines );

    return datalines;
}
```

The flag variable `bgn` is *true* to begin and whenever `'\n'` is encountered. *True* signifies the next character will be the beginning of a line.

Comment: I tried implementing your code but the output I get is "datalines <1>". I understand most of what you did but not enough to know why it doesn't give the desired output. The output I am looking for with this specific file would look like "datalines <11>".

Comment: I admit to typos in the early version of this answer. Please try with this current version. I've just tried it with the sample data you posted and the output was the correct 11 lines found...

Comment: Thank you!   `:-)` If you have a specific question about the above, I'd be happy to try to explain.

Comment: I think I understand what you did for the most part. Since I don't have too much experience with programming yet, it takes me a minute to comprehend. This is also our first time dealing with reading and writing to files so it's taking me some time to understand what is happening. Also, I really appreciate your answer since I've been stuck on this for a few days due to my workload.

Comment: @Fe2O3, UV for handling many issues, yet using `for()` here looks abusive.  IMHO, better to use `for()` in iterative cases.  A `while()` makes more sense here.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica You may be right, but this was an opportunity to launch another salvo in my war against curly braces... `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

As code is looking for the occurrence of a `'\n'` followed by something other than a `'#'`, a space, or presumable any white-space consider coding that directly.

```
int previous = '\n';
int ch;
while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
  datalines += previous == '\n' && !isspace(ch) && ch != '#';
  previous = ch;
}
```